# Cassandra batch size

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-jdbc

I have 6 Cassandra nodes mainly used for writing (95%). 
What's the best approach to inserting data - individual inserts or batches? reason says batches are to be used, while keeping the "batch size" under 5kb to avoid node instability:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6487

Do these 5kb concern the size of the queries, as in number of chars * bytes_per_char? are there any performance drawbacks to fully running individual inserts?

Answer (score 1):

Batch will increase performance if used for a single partition. You are able to get more through put of data inserted.